# Using XPATH to get text AFTER one closed tag and BEFORE the beginning of another specific tag?

Tags: html, xpath

I'm using XPATH to extract information from a website which generates data of the following structure:

```
<span class="classA">
    <span class="classA1">aaa:</span> <a href="bbb"><strong>ccc</strong></a><br>
    <span class="classA1">ddd:</span> eee<br>
    <span class="classA1">fff:</span> <b>ggg gg </b><br>
    ...
    <span class="classA1">hhh:</span>
        <a href="iii">jjj</a>,
        ...
        <a href="kkk">lll</a><br>
        <br>
</span>
<span class="classB">mmm <b>nnn</b> ...
        <br><br>
</span>
<span class="classA">
    <span class="classA1">ooo:</span> ppp<br>
    <span class="classA1">qqq:</span> rrr<br>
    ...
</span>
```

A few things to note first:

1. the exact number of **<span class="classA1">** tags varies
2. the **<a>** tags after **<span class="classA1">hhh:<span>** varies

To extract what follows the individual classA1 spans, I use this XPATH definition:

```
//span[contains(text(),'aaa:')]//following::text()[1]
//span[contains(text(),'ddd:')]//following::text()[1]

//span[contains(text(),'fff:')]//following::text()[1]
...
```

And so on.

Trying to extract the text **after** **<span class="classA1">hhh:<span>**, that is, either the plain text "jjj" and "lll" or the whole html part (i.e. *"<a href="iii">jjj</a>,...<a href="kkk">lll</a>"*), I keep running into problems.

Since, as I mention above, the number of tags there may vary greatly and is unpredictable, I cannot simply identify them by index number. And if I use the following, I also get everything that follows including the following classB span, which I definitely don't need or want.

```
//span[contains(text(),'hhh:')]//following::text()
```

Can you, please, suggest an XPATH solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify: what exactly are you trying to find here?

Comment: @Prophet Hi. I'm trying to extract merely and exclusively the text (or portion of html) following "hhh:" and preceding the next span. In my example, it's "jjj" and "lll".

Comment: Did my solution resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since your source html shows indention not corresponding the parent/child relation, it is not totally clear but maybe this helps:

```
//span[contains(.,'mmm')]/preceding::span[contains(.,'hhh:')][1]/following-sibling::a[not(span[contains(.,'mmm')])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what are you asking for, this should give you all the `a` elements coming after the `<span class="classA1">hhh:</span>` element:

```xml
//span[@class='classA1' and text()='hhh']/following-sibling::a
```

Now you can iterate over the list or resulting `a` elements and extract their texts.
Alternatively you can get their texts directly with this:

```xml
//span[@class='classA1' and text()='hhh']/following-sibling::a/text()
```